# create form customization option in .net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, model-view-controller

I want to create a web application that will enable users to create a dynamic form similar to that of "add new form" provided by Zoho people.I don't have knowledge on how they are doing it.

But what I have done so far is I provided a list of tool box controls provided with drag and drop option so that I can drag a control and drop in my form. This was a simple idea that came to me. But my question is is there any other and effective way of letting the application users generate custom form.

Answer (score 0):

Try generating the JSon based on your drag&drop items collection. Take a look at the JSon Form https://github.com/joshfire/jsonform.